# In the "Simply Easy!" paper, why is it safe to evaluate types in the empty environment?

Tags: design, dependent-type, type-checking

The paper in question: [An Implementation of a Dependently Typed Lambda Calculus](http://strictlypositive.org/Easy.pdf) by Andres Löh, Conor McBride and Wouter Swierstra.

I'm wondering whether it's correct in what's it is doing. Precisely on page 7. In type checker. It's got these evaluations with empty environments. Eg. `let v = eval↓ t []`. Precisely when these are evaluated, could it crash to the `d !! i` in the Figure 4?

Dependently typed languages are related to implementation of proof assistants.

Comment: Is `t` not supposed to be closed under the context (ie. in this case it cannot be a Var)?

Comment: I'd like to see how you would connect the issue of type checking (in Haskell) to the site's focus on proof assistants.  The Question in its present form is terse.

Comment: It's a dependently typed language being typechecked. It is related to implementation of proof assistants.

Comment: I vote to reopen since I think this question is on-topic. It is definitely relevant to anyone interested in dependently-typed proof assistants (including Coq, Lean, Agda, which dominate this SE already).

Comment: Specifically, figure 12 has $\mathtt{type}_{\uparrow}$ invoke $\mathtt{eval}_{\downarrow}~t~[]$, and you're worried that might throw errors or be buggy?

Comment: Can someone from Glasgow please tell Conor McBride that he is needed over here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All is well.

The implementation distinguishes between bound variables, represented as `Bound i` where `i :: Int` and free variables, represented as `Par n` where `n :: Name`. The evaluation function `eval↑` in Figure 4 converts names to values using `vpar` and it replaces bound variables by looking them up in the environment (this is the line with `d !! i`).

In Figure 12 there are several calls of the form `eval↓ τ []`. These are valid because in all cases `τ` does not contain any "exposed" bound variables, therefore it is safe to evaluate it in the empty environment (`τ` may contain free variables, but those are not problematic).
Indeed, the clause for typing an abstraction `Lam e` in the definition of `type↓` typechecks `e` by first replacing the bound variable `0` with a free variable of the form `Par (Bound i)`, where `i` counts the abstraction depth. This way we make sure that an "exposed" bound variable will never be  encountered.